# How to mock UITouches in regression tests?

Tags: ios, testing, uikit, regression

How would you set up regression tests that mock UITouches?

I am developing an iOS-game and want to have some regression tests for core functionality. I would need to trigger calls to touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event etc. automatically for a fixed list of fake touches then I could automatically evaluate the test result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public constructor, but people have found a way, see

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Comment: Sounds good. I'll give it a try. Will accept answer or report back afterwards.

Comment: This indeed worked for me! Few changes required: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724233/simulating-uitouch-in-xcode-4-5-programmatically-uispec, modify for ARC and I also need to set locationInWindow for UITouch.